# Flutter Windows Application fails to compile

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I want to debug the flutter demo application on windows x64 device.but it always fails with 1 error and 1 warning this is my Debug console :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
F:\flut\flutter_application_5\windows\runner\utils.cpp(52,43): error C2220:  warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated [F:\flut\flutter_application_5\build\windows\runner\flutter_application_5.vcxproj]
F:\flut\flutter_application_5\windows\runner\utils.cpp(52,43): warning C4018:  '>': signed/unsigned mismatch [F:\flut\flutter_application_5\build\windows\runner\flutter_application_5.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

and here is my flutter doctor log :

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (6 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\MEMPHIS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.1.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
    • Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.1.28917.181
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\MEMPHIS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.63

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
exit code 0
```

I can debug the demo app on edge, chrome, android without any problem
so What wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (Microsoft) C++ compiler is raising a warning inside the `utils.cpp` file:

> `windows\runner\utils.cpp(52,43): warning C4018:  '>': signed/unsigned mismatch`

It's configured to treat warnings as errors, so the compile fails with:

> `windows\runner\utils.cpp(52,43): error C2220:  warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated`

I don't believe that `/WX` (warnings as errors) can be configured other than by the build script (which turns it ON).

I suspect one of two things:

- The Enterprise edition of the compiler (which you have) is slightly more picky than the Community edition (which I have). You could edit the project file to turn off warnings-as-errors, or add an exception for this warning (more below).
- Your compiler needs upgrading. I've got 16.**11**.something; you've got 16.**1**.something. Run the *Visual Studio Installer* again to upgrade it. (For example: I just ran it, and it's suggesting I upgrade from 16.11.10 to 16.11.18...).

### Editing the project file

The `winapp.vcxproj` project file is (apparently) generated by CMake. Edit `windows\CMakeLists.txt` and change the following line:

```
  target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE /W4 /WX /wd"4100")
```

Make it look like this:

```
  target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE /W4 /WX /wd"4100" /wd4018)
```

I don't know where the quotes come from; you might need them. Alternatively, remove the `/WX` bit.

Comment: oh thank you sir,I didnt update visual studio in my win machine, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, [this](https://github.com/bdlukaa/fluent_ui/issues/889) solution by "bdlukaa" solved it:

1. delete `windows` folder
2. run `flutter create .` in terminal to recreate the windows folder
3. rerun your app (I hope it works )